# Texture2D.LoadImage async

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Simple and short question,

I download a texture from a server (185MB texture atlas). But creating the texture out of the bytes using `Texture2D.LoadImage` blocks the application for about 4 seconds. How can I create this texture asynchronously?

```
// Load texture atlas texture data
HttpWebRequest atlasTextureRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp(EntityDatabase.ATLAS_TEXTURE_PATH);
WebResponse atlasTextureResponse = await atlasTextureRequest.GetResponseAsync();

byte[] atlasTextureData = await EntityDatabase.ReadStreamAsync(
    atlasTextureResponse.GetResponseStream(),
    (int)atlasTextureResponse.ContentLength
);

EntityDatabase.TextureAtlasTexture = new Texture2D(1, 1);
EntityDatabase.TextureAtlasTexture.LoadImage(atlasTextureData);
```

Answer (score 3):

OP:

> How can I create this texture asynchronously?

### Short answer

You can't, *["The C# API's for Texture creation (E.g. new `Texture2D`) must always be called on the main thread"](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture-allowThreadedTextureCreation.html)*.

### Longer answer

The `async/await` support brought to us via .NET 4.x allows for *asynchronous I/O* and *asynchronous compute*. Generally there are no barriers to their use but in **Unity** 3D **there is**, particularly *compute*.

Your code below is I/O bound and is an example of asynchronous I/O and Unity should not have any qualms with it.  The bit that will pose a problem will be your texture creation.  Read on.

```
WebResponse atlasTextureResponse = await atlasTextureRequest.GetResponseAsync();

byte[] atlasTextureData = await EntityDatabase.ReadStreamAsync(
    atlasTextureResponse.GetResponseStream(),
    (int)atlasTextureResponse.ContentLength
);
```

Creating a texture in Unity is *CPU-bound* and is an example of a compute operation.  To perform compute operations in the background you would normally do something like:

```
var stuff = 
    await Task.Run (() => ConstructSomethingThatTakesALongTimeSynchonosouly ();
```

...which is fine but we want to create a `Texture2D` so we could try to do something like:

```
public class LoadTextureAsyncExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start runs in the main thread
    private async void Start()
    {
        var textureBytes = await DownloadTextureAsync();
        _texture = await Task.Run(() => CreateTexture2D(textureBytes));
    }
 
    private async Task<byte[]> DownloadTextureAsync()
    {
        // essentially your code above.  
        // This method will be a mixture of main/pool thread
    }

    private Texture2D CreateTexture2D(byte[] textureBytes)
    {
        // this method is running in a thread pool thread
        var texture = new Texture2D(1, 1);
        texture.LoadRawTextureData(textureBytes);
        return texture;
    }
```

...now whilst `CreateTexture2D` will run in a thread-pool thread and won't block the main thread, the code will **fail** at the point of creating a `Texture2D` due to it running in a thread **different from the main thread**.

Textures created by C# must be created in the main thread.  You could try setting `Texture.allowThreadedTextureCreation = true` but that won't work either. Unity says it best below.

Unity (my emphasis):

> [Texture.allowThreadedTextureCreation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture-allowThreadedTextureCreation.html)
> **Description**
> Allow Unity internals to perform Texture creation on any thread (rather than the dedicated render thread).
> **Note: The C# API's for Texture creation (E.g. new Texture2D) must always be called on the main thread. This setting does not alter that requirement.**

Comment: That last part leaves me wondering what allowThreadedTextureCreation is even for. To me it reads like the one thing it's meant to do doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Extending on [Micky's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69139826/7111561)

Currently the only built-in (without the need of additional native code) non-blocking way to load a texture would be using

[`UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture.html) in a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)

Example from the API

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(GetText(SOME_URL));
}

IEnumerator DownloadTexture(string url)
{
    using (UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(url))
    {
        yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();

        if (uwr.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
        {
            Debug.Log(uwr.error);
        }
        else
        {
            // Get downloaded asset bundle
            var texture = DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(uwr);
        }
    }
}
```

This also works for local file paths on your device.

If this directly is not an option you could still download and store the file temporary on your device asynchronously and then use the `UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture` in order to load that locally stored file and then delete the local file again.

Comment: Does it really not block, not even in DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent ? So we need to use a method intended for online access to load local textures without blocking? If Unity was able to make this, why didn't they make it for the regular texture-loading methods?

Comment: @pete because if there already is a method for this then why create a second one? ;) As another example on Android devices the same is used to access text files within the streaming assets folder .. because it is compressed into the app package so you can't use normal file IO .. doesn't mean it is a web request in the background, that's just the name of the top level API

Comment: I just checked and this method genuinely does allow you to perform a Texture2D.LoadImage task asynchronously, reducing the time the main thread is blocked when loading a single image from ~600ms to ~0ms on a slow test device for me. If you already have the image data in memory, it is (ridiculously) far more desirable to *save the image to file storage and then load it again* than to use Texture2D.LoadImage(). (Unless blocking the main thread isn't an issue, such as a during a static loading screen.)

Comment: (Or with images so small that the blocking time won't impact framerate.)